# how to combine two socket io apps in one server ? ( Tictactoe game and Chatapp)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Both Tictactoe and Chatapp use socket io in Nodejs. I want to combine Tictactoe game and Chatapp in one means while playing tictactoe game user can chat in chatapp which is embedded in tictactoe game webpage by iframe ( embedded chatapp webpage in tictactoe webpage ).
So I combined both the server files in one server file .

```
app.get("/chat-box", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/static/HTML/chat-box.html");
});

app.get("/tic-tac-toe", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/static/HTML/tic-tac-toe.html");
});
```

I tried by both the methods . 1) First method is to write both codes in single io.on.connection

```
 io.on("connection", function (socket) {
...
Tictactoe code
Chatapp code
}
```

2. Second method is to write separate  io.on.connection codes for both

```
    io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    ...
    Tictactoe code
    }
 io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    ...
    Chat app code
    }
```

But the problem is that as chatapp is embedded in game by iframe tag so problems is that tictactoe user gets connected twice so that user doesn't get connected with another player and so game doesn't work but chatapp works.

Comment: You can think of Client as requester and Server as head who fulfills the request upon some validations. You can host your game logic as well as chat room on the same server on the same-port `Socket.IO` has a feature called rooms which you can utilize to make a match-making logic then make pair of users and throw them in a room where they can play and communicate in the real-time.

Comment: You can use socket.io namespaces to have one socket.io server, but have separate ways for clients to connect for each app and separate server-side connection code for your two apps.